# How to check what size the font in react code is

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to figure out how to see the px size for this font is in vscode, the following line of code is for header 3 is

`h3 { font-family: ${(props) => props.theme.font.font1.demi}; font-size: ${(props) => props.theme.fontSize.large_28};`

I want to figure out what font size is large_28, Thank you!